# R package 'TranslateR' does not show the translated results (2)

Tags: r

I am trying to use TranslateR package in R to translate the column of the data from Korean to English. I tried using the following code:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
library(translateR)

##Install development version of translateR
devtools::install_github("ChristopherLucas/translateR")
foodcode_translated <- translateR::translate(dataset = food_code,
                            content.field = '식품코드명',
                            google.api.key = 
                            "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                            source.lang = 'ko',
                            target.lang = 'en')
```

- I successfully got the google API key.

The codes above do not show any error but there is no change in the data frame after the codes are run.

Can anybody tell me what the issue is?

Thanks